# PHP separate variable container

Tags: php

I have a variable that contains a date

```
$date = "04/18/2017 04:02 PM";
```

This comes from a date field, This field will always contain a date like this, and What I'm trying to do is separating the date from the time

So how do i go about getting only *04/18/2017* from the variable or the time *04:02 PM* ?

Thanks.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php and then http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just do a simple [explode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php):

```
$explode = explode($date, ' ', 2);
$date = $explode[0];
$time = $explode[1];
```

Comment: Or: `$date = "04/18/2017 04:02 PM";
print date('Y-m-d',strtotime($date));`

Comment: That requires conversion, and some overhead. Mine simply splits the string in half, and pulls the different parts.

Comment: In this case, he will come back and will ask, how can I get the name of the day:D My answer is more flexible, and I think dates should handle like date not an string and array. Your solution is requires conversion also. You convert the string to array :)

Comment: Thank you both :* I will use explode, Don't worry i got the "day" too by splitting into three pieces due to the spaces :D